# django datetime declaration error

Tags: python, django, django-models

I added the following code in models.py :

```
class Conference(models.Model):
    conf_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=500)     
    note = models.TextField(max_length=500)     
    note2 = models.TextField(max_length=500)     
    date_from = models.DateField()
    date_to = models.DateField()
    time_from = models.TimeField(default='HH:MM:ss')
    time_to = models.TimeField(default='HH:MM:ss')
```

After that I ran migration commands and I got the following traceback :

```
WARNINGS:
?: (mysql.W002) MySQL Strict Mode is not set for database connection 'appadmin'
    HINT: MySQL's Strict Mode fixes many data integrity problems in MySQL, such as data truncation upon insertion, by escalating warnings into errors. It is strongly recommended you activate it. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/databases/#mysql-sql-mode
?: (mysql.W002) MySQL Strict Mode is not set for database connection 'default'
    HINT: MySQL's Strict Mode fixes many data integrity problems in MySQL, such as data truncation upon insertion, by escalating warnings into errors. It is strongly recommended you activate it. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/databases/#mysql-sql-mode
?: (urls.W005) URL namespace 'dev_app' isn't unique. You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, dev_app, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying dev_app.0016_auto_20180112_0630...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 86, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/schema.py", line 48, in add_field
    super(DatabaseSchemaEditor, self).add_field(model, field)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 414, in add_field
    definition, params = self.column_sql(model, field, include_default=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 154, in column_sql
    default_value = self.effective_default(field)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 228, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 766, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 2277, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 2272, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 2259, in to_python
    params={'value': value},
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: [u"'null' value has an invalid format. It must be in HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]] format."]
```

Even after I reverted the code in models.py, the traceback has persisted.

I need help understanding the traceback.

The code was working properly before the changes in models were applied. The models migrated properly. 
I also flushed the database and tried to migrate again, it gave the same result.

Comment: Try to delete the database and migrate again. It looks like you already have some data in `Conference` table

Comment: @ArpitSolanki I have done that. I deleted the database and now each time I try to migrate, it throws the traceback I have posted.

Comment: you should see answer below. It would solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `time_from` and `time_to` default is wrong. You should provide a default value not a format. If your model is new remove the migration file (I think `dev_app.0016_auto_20180112_0630`) change default values and run `manage.py makemigrations` again.

Comment: Thanks ! worked like a charm. I was struggling with it for a while. Btw, how did you figure out that migration file should be removed ?

Comment: @s_user Your welcome :) Your stack trace shows the migration has failed to apply. You could remove migrations that you didn't applied anywhere without harm. It's not a "should" you could have modified it by hand and remove wrong defaults from it. Removing and recreating is just easier.